# Reading Clipboard with WIC

Tags: c++, clipboard, wic

I'm trying to write a function to read images copied to the clipboard with Windows Imaging Component. Currently my code is based off how I load resources but modified to work with the clipboard. everything up to initializing the stream works fine but once I try to use `CreateDecoderFromeStream` it fails. I've tried copying images from numerous places to no avail. Is there something different about the copied image format that can't be read by WIC?

Here's my code below...

Creating a memory object to read from the clipboard

```
COMStreamSPtr WIC::createStreamFromClipboard() {
    IStream* ipStream = NULL;
    COMStreamSPtr stream = nullptr;
    CoInitialize(nullptr);
    if (!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_BITMAP) && !IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_DIB) && !IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_DIBV5))
        goto Return;

    if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
        goto Return;

    // Load the clipboard
    HGLOBAL hMem = GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
    if (hMem == NULL || hMem == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        hMem = GetClipboardData(CF_DIB);
    if (hMem == NULL || hMem == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        hMem = GetClipboardData(CF_DIBV5);
    if (hMem == NULL || hMem == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        goto CloseClipboard;

    // Lock the clipboard, getting a pointer to its data
    LPVOID pvSourceClipboardData = GlobalLock(hMem);
    if (pvSourceClipboardData == NULL)
        goto CloseClipboard;

    // Read the clipboard data size
    DWORD dwClipboardSize = GlobalSize(hMem);
    if (dwClipboardSize == 0)
        goto GlobalUnlock;

    // Allocate memory to hold the clipboard data
    HGLOBAL hgblClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, dwClipboardSize);
    if (hgblClipboardData == NULL)
        goto GlobalUnlock;

    // Get a pointer to the allocated memory
    LPVOID pvClipboardData = GlobalLock(hgblClipboardData);
    if (pvClipboardData == NULL)
        goto FreeData;

    // Copy the data from the clipboard to the new memory block
    CopyMemory(pvClipboardData, pvSourceClipboardData, dwClipboardSize);
    GlobalUnlock(hgblClipboardData);

    // Create a stream on the HGLOBAL containing the data
    if (SUCCEEDED(CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hgblClipboardData, TRUE, &ipStream))) {
        stream = std::make_shared<COMStream>(ipStream);
        goto CloseClipboard;
    }

FreeData:
    // Couldn't create stream; free the memory
    GlobalFree(hgblClipboardData);
GlobalUnlock:
    // Unlock the clipboard data
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
CloseClipboard:
    // Close the clipboard
    CloseClipboard();
Return:
    // No need to unlock or free the resource
    CoUninitialize(); // CoInialize is called by my COMObjects in the constructor so this is just decrementing the count.
    return stream;
}
```

Elsewhere in the code using the returned stream.

```
WICBitmapDecoderSPtr WIC::createDecoderFromStream(COMStreamSPtr stream) {
    if (isCOMObjectNull(stream))
        return nullptr;

    IWICImagingFactory* ipFactory = NULL;
    IWICBitmapDecoder* ipDecoder = NULL;
    WICBitmapDecoderSPtr decoder = nullptr;

    // Create the factory
    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ipFactory))))
        goto Return;

    // Create the decoder
    if (FAILED(ipFactory->CreateDecoderFromStream(stream->ipObject, NULL, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand, &ipDecoder)))
        goto ReleaseFactory; // FAILS HERE

    decoder = std::make_shared<WICBitmapDecoder>(ipDecoder);
ReleaseFactory:
    ipFactory->Release();
Return:
    return decoder;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out how to do this. What I did is I used `IWICImagingFactory`'s `CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP` function. Since reading an `HBITMAP` from the clipboard work trivial, the solution becomes pretty straight forward.

```
IWICBitmapSource* WIC::readSourceFromClipboard() {
    IWICBitmapSource* ipSource = NULL;
    if (Clipboard::containsFormat(CF_BITMAP)) {
        if (OpenClipboard(NULL)) {
            HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
            ipSource = createSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap);
            CloseClipboard();
        }
    }
    return ipSource;
}

IWICBitmapSource* WIC::createSourceFromHBitmap(HBITMAP hBitmap) {
    if (hBitmap == NULL)
        return NULL;

    IWICImagingFactory* ipFactory = NULL;
    IWICBitmap* ipBitmap = NULL;

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the factory
    if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&ipFactory))))
        goto Return;

    // Create the bitmap
    if (FAILED(ipFactory->CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(hBitmap, NULL, WICBitmapIgnoreAlpha, &ipBitmap)))
        goto ReleaseFactory;

ReleaseFactory:
    ipFactory->Release();
Return:
    CoUninitialize();
    return ipBitmap;
}
```